# А в свою очередь это делает то-то

Tags: правописание

Нужно ли тире перед `это`:

> А в свою очередь это делает то-то

Comment: in this particular case prior research has not been indicated

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Тире нужно перед "это", когда у нас есть подлежащее и сказуемое, выраженные существительными.

> **Глобус** - это **чучело** земли. (с)

А в вашем примере "это" - подлежащее, "делает" - сказуемое.